# What Does "Socialist Promise" Mean in This Context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am reading an article from The Economist and its title is ["Suffering from shortages? How to survive without puppies, fake tan or IKEA."](https://www.economist.com/1843/2021/11/25/suffering-from-shortages-how-to-survive-without-puppies-fake-tan-or-ikea)

The writer talks about her relationship with IKEA in this part.

> Although the monolithic furniture retailer is obviously in it for profit, the vaguely ***socialist promise*** behind ikea’s “democratic design principles” (form, function, sustainability, quality and low price) typically translates into offering the nicest version of a thing that can be made affordably.

I am not sure what "socialist promise" refer to in this context and why "offering the nicest version of a thing that can be made affordably" is socialist?

Comment: Do you understand what 'socialist' means, and how it might mean 'relating to various egalitarian economic and political theories or movements', and how that might 'vaguely' include 'offering the nicest version of a thing that can be made affordably'?

Comment: It doesn't say that "offering the nicest version of a thing that can be made affordably" is socialist, it says that there is a "vaguely socialist promise" **behind** Ikea's design principles, and that the promise typically *turns into* offering the nicest version of a thing etc.

Comment: I thought socialism referred to the theory advocating state ownership of capital or industry. So I didn't know why the word socialist was used here, because it doesn't mention any state ownership.

Answer (score 1):

It is **vaguely** socialist. This means that we are not going to be able to pin down how it conforms to a political theory in any detail.

But it talks about "democratic design principles" - so not autocratic but **vaguely** egalitarian, or "left-wing".  The general style of IKEA is in contrast to furniture made by craftspeople to very high standards, and sold at prices that only the rich can afford.  Instead, it is supposed to be *design for the common people*. Again **vaguely** socialist.

Comment: I kind of correlated socialism with autocracy, because some countries call themselves socialist countries but are in fact ruled by dictators. But I should remind myself the essence of socialism should have been good.

Comment: There are quotation marks for the phrase democratic design principles, could you please tell me whether this is for emphasis or has any connotation?

Comment: I used quote marks because I was quoting from your question.  I don't know why the Economist used them. I assume they are quoting from some source text. such as https://ikeamuseum.com/blobiicsikeamu4941109594/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/pressrelease-220419-en-Democratic-Design.pdf  The use of quote marks means you should read this as "The thing that IKEA calls 'democratic design principles'. " That is, it is not a term invented by the writer at the Economist.

Comment: similarly I use quote marks around "left-wing" to mean "the  thing that people call 'left wing'".

Answer (score 0):

**the vaguely socialist promise** ~ the vaguely egalitarian and optimistic assurance.

The European understanding of socialist and socialism has nothing to do with the countries ruled by lunatics and autocrats, and nothing to do with communism.

Socialist and socialism relate to a general ideal of the lessening of the gap between rich and poor, educated and uneducated. It does include public works for the benefit of society and may include public ownership of essential resources, such as the water supply.

**Promise** (uncountable) in this sense is figurative:

OED:

> **Promise** (n.) **4.a. An indication of a future event or condition; esp. one giving strong or reasonable grounds for the expectation of
> future achievements or good results; the quality of potential
> excellence.**
>
> 1992   Canad. Geographic Jan. 86/3   *The last decade of the 20th
> century is a time of great promise, great risk and great complexity.*